# How can I determine what Intents a third-party app supports?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I'd like to invoke third-party apps to enhance my own.  For instance, I'd like to allow users of my app to use programs like [CamScanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.camscanner&hl=en) to capture images as an alternative to the camera.  I'd like to be able to suggest recommended third-party apps that work well as intent alternatives to bring better functionality to my app.

Is there a public manifest after installation or better yet some indication in the Play market page for the app that shows which `Intents` it supports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is http://openintents.org - if it is listed there.

Answer (score 3):

You can learn about activity names from the system Settings/Applications screen.

No matter what, you'll be able to invoke their main activity, like this:

```
startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.theirpackage"));
```

Now, non-main activities that are not explicitly documented are another matter. Even if you get the manifest text, this might or might not help you figure out the invokation protocol; the activity might rely on intent extras that the manifest says nothing about.

And no matter what, you never know if the activities in the app rely on a certain order of invokation. Unless an activity was explicitly built for third party reuse, you never know if it's ready for reuse. I can easily envision the scenario where an activity relies on a static variable that's initialized in another activity, which is always started first over the normal flow of the app. If you invoke the dependent activity out of order, be ready for crashes.

That said, it's fairly easy to get the XML manifest for an app. First, get an emulator image with Google Market in it (search around, those are all over the 'Net), or a rooted device. Install the app from the Market. Pull the APK from the device using `ADB` or Eclipse. Then use the `apktool` to take the APK apart. It decompiles the manifest into a readable XML form.

Comment: You can use Sony's AppXplore app on normal device to get other apps' AndroidManifest.xml without root.

Answer (score 0):

In case of the CamScanner app, it exists a public API.
https://dev.camscanner.net/

It requires to sign an agreement.